# javascript async and callback waiting for push to finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I hava a callback function that calls multiple times

```
this.callback = (file) => {
        Api.exec('image', file).then(data => {
            temp.push(data);
            console.log(temp); 
            this.doneUploaded(temp);
        });
}
```

which print

```
[Object]
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object]
```

how do I wait all promised has finished? use settimeout is a way but it's not a good solution, I can't get the exact time when the upload will be finish.

Comment: *how do I wait all promised has finished?* - `Promise.all` ? seems a good fit - though, based on below comment, seems like Promises are not always the solution

Comment: How is `this.callback` supposed to know how many times it will be called?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Not necessarily, in this case. A call might finish before the next one is called. We don't know how the callback is called.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't considered that Promises are not appropriate for this code at all

Comment: Making a wild assumption here. The code seems perform an image upload. The caller of the callback can iterate through all the images (or whatever your flavour is) the user (or system) wants to upload, and right at the end, fire the completion method. @Alex Yong, can you supply the code that invokes the callback?

Comment: @RohanBüchner exactly! line no.45 here https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component/blob/master/example/src/example_default.jsx. If the user drag and dropped 3 files, the this.callback will trigger 3 times.

Comment: Then it seems like important info is missing to your question. Currently without your code (on github) it's hard to know what is your actual problem, or what could define a completed set of operations that you are waiting for